# Pushing to and pulling from two Git repositories simultaneously

Tags: git, github

What I want to achieve might not be possible, and sound strange at first, but I have a good reason for it.

I have a project that i version-controlled with Git. This is an example folder structure

```
- app  << git repository root
  - themes
  - plugins << sub-repository only for 'plugins'
  - assets
- core
- shared
```

The `plugins` folder is ignored by the main (top-level) Git repository (added to `.gitignore`).

However, I'd like to push the `plugins` folder to its repository when I execute `git push origin master` at the root repository. Similarly, I want the sub repository in `plugins` to be pulled when I execute `git pull origin master` at the root repository.

Is this possible to achieve? Are git submodules a solution here? If so, what is the way to go?

Comment: This is exactly an example for submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair It's close to what's int he examples, but not exactly. I'd like to be able to commit changes in the submodule directory in my local repo by running `git commit` commiting in the root repository, so that I do not have to go to the subdirectory and commit there.

Comment: I belive that this should be handled by the client of your choice (like for SVN, where TortoiseSVN gives you the option to commit to externals within a root commit).